# Python: How to extract floating point numbers from a text file with mixed content?

Tags: python, floating-point, csv

I have a tab delimited text file with the following data:

```
    ahi1
    b/se
ahi 
test    -2.435953
        1.218364
    ahi2
    b/se
ahi 
test    -2.001858
        1.303935
```

I want to extract the two floating point numbers to a separate csv file with two columns, ie.

```
-2.435953 1.218264

-2.001858 1.303935
```

Currently my hack attempt is:

```
 import csv
 from itertools import islice
 results = csv.reader(open('test', 'r'), delimiter="\n")

 list(islice(results,3))
 print results.next()
 print results.next()
 list(islice(results,3))
 print results.next()
 print results.next()
```

Which is not ideal.   I am a Noob to Python so I apologise in advance and thank you for your time.

Comment: Note that where you are consuming the values, a slightly more efficient method (avoiding building a list) is to do `next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)` - as taken from the `consume()` recipe in the [itertools docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code to do the job:

```
import re

# this is the same data just copy/pasted from your question
data = """    ahi1
    b/se
ahi 
test    -2.435953
        1.218364
    ahi2
    b/se
ahi 
test    -2.001858
        1.303935"""

# what we're gonna do, is search through it line-by-line
# and parse out the numbers, using regular expressions

# what this basically does is, look for any number of characters
# that aren't digits or '-' [^-\d]  ^ means NOT
# then look for 0 or 1 dashes ('-') followed by one or more decimals
# and a dot and decimals again: [\-]{0,1}\d+\.\d+
# and then the same as first..
pattern = re.compile(r"[^-\d]*([\-]{0,1}\d+\.\d+)[^-\d]*")

results = []
for line in data.split("\n"):
    match = pattern.match(line)
    if match:
        results.append(match.groups()[0])

pairs = []
i = 0
end = len(results)
while i < end - 1:
    pairs.append((results[i], results[i+1]))
    i += 2

for p in pairs:
    print "%s, %s" % (p[0], p[1])
```

The output:

```
>>>
-2.435953, 1.218364
-2.001858, 1.303935
```

Instead of printing out the numbers, you could save them in a list and zip them together afterwards..
I'm using the [python regular expression framework](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) to parse the text. I can only recommend you pick up regular expressions if you don't already know it. I find it very useful to parse through text and all sorts of machine generated output-files.

EDIT:

Oh and BTW, if you're worried about the performance, I tested on my slow old 2ghz IBM T60 laptop and I can parse a megabyte in about 200ms using the regex.

UPDATE:
I felt kind, so I did the last step for you :P

Comment: Thank you! Fantastic effort, it works perfectly as above and with a little tinkering it even works with my original files (I mentioned that I was a Noob didn't I?). I will totally check out the regexp stuff also, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Note that you can simplify this with list comprhensions. `matches = (pattern.match(line) for line in data.split("\n"))` `results = [match.group(0) for match in matches if match]` for the first list construction. For the second, you should look into the itertools `grouper()` recipe.

Comment: Thanks Lattyware, I will try that.   I'm not sure that I followed your comment above but I will try to understand that also.   Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help

```
zip(*[results]*5)
```

eg

```
import csv
from itertools import izip
results = csv.reader(open('test', 'r'), delimiter="\t")
for result1, result2 in (x[3:5] for x in izip(*[results]*5)):
    ... # do something with the result
```

Comment: Thanks for considering my question and answering so promptly.   I am new to python and programming so unfortunately I haven't been able to get it to work as yet but I will ... eventually!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tricky enough but more eloquent and sequential solution:

```
$ grep -v "ahi" myFileName | grep -v se | tr -d "test\" " | awk 'NR%2{printf $0", ";next;}1'
-2.435953, 1.218364
-2.001858, 1.303935
```

How it works: Basically remove specific text lines, then remove unwanted text in lines, then join every second line with formatting. I just added the comma for beautification purposes. Leave the comma out of awks printf ", " if you don't need it.